# Django==3.2.15 celery v5.1.2 and jango-celery-beat==2.2.1 enable task and nothing heppens

Tags: django, django-celery, django-celery-beat

Ok all day trying to figure out what is wrong.

mysite.settings

```
"""
Django settings for mysite project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 2.1.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/
"""

import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'your_secret_key_here'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'correlator.apps.CorrelatorConfig',
    'reviews.apps.ReviewsConfig',
    'parameters.apps.ParametersConfig',
    'trex',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework',
    #'django_filters',
    'rest_framework_swagger', # optional, creates browsable API docs
    'easy_thumbnails', # Required by `content_image` plugin
    'celery',
    'django_celery_beat',
    'iris',
    'django_celery_results',

]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'mysite.mycsrfmiddleware.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'mysite.mymiddleware.CorrelatorControllerMiddleware',
    
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'mysite.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',

            ],
            
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'mysite.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#databases


DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'postgres',
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'PASSWORD': 'M@ster449644p',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}

# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True

CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = ["http://localhost:8000"]
#CSRF_COOKIE_DOMAIN = '.localhost'

# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

MESSAGE_STORAGE = 'django.contrib.messages.storage.cookie.CookieStorage'

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.AutoField'

REST_FRAMEWORK = { 'DEFAULT_SCHEMA_CLASS': 'rest_framework.schemas.coreapi.AutoSchema' }

CELERY_BEAT_SCHEDULER = 'django_celery_beat.schedulers:DatabaseScheduler'

# # Celery Broker - Redis  
CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'amqp://localhost'  
# Celery Configuration Options
CELERY_TASK_TRACK_STARTED = True
CELERY_TASK_TIME_LIMIT = 30 * 60
CELERY_CACHE_BACKEND = 'django-cache' 
# CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['application/json']  
# CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'  
# CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'json'  
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'django-db'
CELERY_TIMEZONE = "Asia/HongKnong"
```

mysite.celery.py

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
import os
from celery import Celery
import requests
from django.utils import timezone
#from celery.contrib import rdb

# set the default Django settings module for the 'celery' program.
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'mysite.settings')

app = Celery('mysite')

# Optional configuration, see the application user guide.
app.conf.update(
    result_expires=3600,
)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.start()

# Using a string here means the worker doesn't have to serialize
# the configuration object to child processes.
# - namespace='CELERY' means all celery-related configuration keys
#   should have a `CELERY_` prefix.

app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')

# Load task modules from all registered Django app configs.
app.autodiscover_tasks()

@app.task(bind=True)
def debug_task(self):
    print('Request: {0!r}'.format(self.request))

@app.task(bind=True)
def hello_world(self):
    print('Hello world!')
```

beat is installed and runs fine in admin pages can see the hello_world task in the registered tasks and set an interval of 15 seconds

I start celery worker with and get

```
celery -A mysite worker -l INFO -P gevent
celery@DESKTOP-65V2VTJ v5.1.2 (sun-harmonics)       
--- ***** -----
-- ******* ---- Windows-10-10.0.19041-SP0 2022-10-31 15:33:23       
- *** --- * ---
- ** ---------- [config]
- ** ---------- .> app:         mysite:0x28bba8b0ef0
- ** ---------- .> transport:   amqp://guest:**@localhost:5672//    
- ** ---------- .> results:       
- *** --- * --- .> concurrency: 12 (gevent)
-- ******* ---- .> task events: ON--- ***** -----
 -------------- [queues]
                .> celery
  exchange=celery(direct) key=celery


[tasks]
  . correlator.tasks.add
  . correlator.tasks.mul
  . iris.tasks.add
  . iris.tasks.mul
  . mysite.celery.debug_task      
  . mysite.celery.hello_world     
  . reviews.tasks.add
  . reviews.tasks.mul
  . reviews.tasks.rename_widget   

[2022-10-31 15:33:23,540: INFO/MainProcess] Connected to amqp://guest:**@127.0.0.1:5672//
[2022-10-31 15:33:23,544: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: searching for neighbors
[2022-10-31 15:33:24,564: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: all alone       
[2022-10-31 15:33:24,573: WARNING/MainProcess] c:\users\mikeoliver\github\correlator-2\venv\lib\site-packages\celery\fixups\django.py:204: UserWarning: Using settings.DEBUG leads to a memory
            leak, never use this setting in production environments!  leak, never use this setting in 
production environments!''')      

[2022-10-31 15:33:24,574: INFO/MainProcess] celery@DESKTOP-65V2VTJ ready.
[2022-10-31 15:33:24,577: INFO/MainProcess] pidbox: Connected to amqp://guest:**@127.0.0.1:5672//.
```

I start beat

```
celery beat    
celery beat v5.1.2 (sun-harmonics) is starting.
__    -    ... __   -        _
LocalTime -> 2022-10-31 15:34:11 
Configuration ->
    . broker -> amqp://guest:**@localhost:5672//




    . loader -> celery.loaders.default.Loader
    . scheduler -> celery.beat.PersistentScheduler
    . db -> celerybeat-schedule  
    . logfile -> [stderr]@%WARNING
    . maxinterval -> 5.00 minutes (300s)
```

But when I change the schedule or anything in any of the registered tasks I see nothing in any of the three terminals after the save in the runserver terminal.

Comment: Hi, are you trying to save your files and expect it to effect in celery / beats / scheduler? It may need a restart (all celery components) or you may need auto reloader or something (some library) for listening to file changes. Meanwhile celery also has APIs (methods) to control worker/ scheduler remotely / programatically.

Comment: Yes, I expected to be able to change a task in the admin pages and not have to drop down to telnet.  Yes, restarted everything including RabbitMQ, with no effect.  Will try to use command line to see if that works.  But that isn't really a solution, it just eliminates a source of the problem.